# How to call a component function from inside a callback for angular 2 + (razorpay)?

Tags: angular, callback, razorpay

So I am trying to call a function from within a callback response on an api for a payment app razorpay. I cannot use 'this' to call functions within the component as it is within a nested function in the handler. How can I call the function handle_response() from the callback "handler"?

> myComponent.ts

```
var options = {
    "amount": 100, 
    "name": "ABC",
    "currency": "USD",
    "handler": function (response){
        console.log(response);//this returns the expected value
        this.handle_response(response); //does not work as cannot identify 'this'
    }
};
var rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(options);
rzp1.open();

handle_response(_response){....}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `bind` method of your function or the fat arrow syntax from typescript. It would be either:

```js
let options = {
    "amount": 100, 
    "name": "ABC",
    "currency": "USD",
    "handler": function (response){
        console.log(response);//this returns the expected value
        this.handle_response(response); //does not work as cannot identify 'this'
    }.bind(this)
};
let rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(options);
rzp1.open();

handle_response(_response){....}
```

**OR**
you can use javascript arrow function. read more about arrow function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
let options = {
    "amount": 100, 
    "name": "ABC",
    "currency": "USD",
    "handler": (response) => {
        console.log(response);//this returns the expected value
        this.handle_response(response); //does not work as cannot identify 'this'
    }
};
let rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(options);
rzp1.open();

handle_response(_response){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind **this** as a local variable outside of the options and then call this as with local variable  like:-

```
var newThis=this;
    var options = {
    "amount": 100, 
    "name": "ABC",
    "currency": "USD",
    "handler": function (response){
        console.log(response);//this returns the expected value
        newThis.handle_response(response); // 'this' works as new this
    }
};
var rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(options);
rzp1.open();
```